# Allow cloud server behind firewall to communicate to IBM Websphere MQ on local network

Tags: cloud, vmware, ibm-mq, remote-access, remote-server

I have a cloud server that sits behind the firewall (`cloud-server.cat.com`).

I can RDP into it by creating a firewall rule using `VMware vCloud Director`.

I checked and the outbound rule has been created for `port 1414` on `cloud-server.cat.com`

I need to be able to connect `cloud-server.cat.com` to `IBM WebSphere MQ` that's on server here locally (`phoenix.cat.com`).

I can connect using port `1414` from one of the local test servers, but not from `cloud-server.cat.com` server.

I get following error:

```
MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2059'.
A WebSphere MQ error occurred : Completion code 2 Reason code 2059

com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2059'.
        at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:
236)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnecti
on(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:504)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnectio
n(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:545)
        at com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.<init>(StoredManagedConnection.jav
a:95)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConne
ctionManager.java:184)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueMana
gerFactory.java:870)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.procure(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:7
56)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.constructQueueManager(MQQueueManager
Factory.java:704)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.createQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFac
tory.java:170)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.<init>(MQQueueManager.java:598)
        at MsgQueue.DPGReceiver.main(DPGReceiver.java:177)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2059;AMQ9204: Connection to ho
st 'phoenix.cat.com(1414)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;R
C=2059;AMQ9213: A communications error for  occurred. [1=java.net.ConnectExcepti
on[Connection timed out: connect],3=phoenix.cat.com]],3=phoenix.cat.com(
1414),5=RemoteTCPConnection.connnectUsingLocalAddress]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:
1689)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSION.MQCONNX_j(MQSESSION.java:929)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:
225)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2059;AMQ9213: A communications
 error for  occurred. [1=java.net.ConnectException[Connection timed out: connect
],3=phoenix.cat.com]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteTCPConnection.connnectUsingLoca
lAddress(RemoteTCPConnection.java:603)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect(R
emoteTCPConnection.java:938)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.system.RemoteConnection.connect(Remot
eConnection.java:1065)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.system.RemoteConnectionPool.getConnec
tion(RemoteConnectionPool.java:392)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:
1407)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteTCPConnection$2.run(RemoteTCPCo
nnection.java:588)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.internal.RemoteTCPConnection.connnectUsingLoca
lAddress(RemoteTCPConnection.java:579)
        ... 16 more
```

Does anyone know if this is on `WebSphere's` end or it's because my `cloud-server.cat.com`?

Answer (score 4):

That's really hard to say with the information provided. There may be firewall rules inbound on `phoenix.cat.com`, host-based firewall rules on any of the servers, IPSec or any other number of issues at the network level.

At the QMgr level, it's possible that the listener is not running or not listening on the port you expect.

Generally, before trying to test the MQ connectivity, it is a good idea to verify the underlying network connectivity.  You can do this by telnetting from the client-side to the QMgr side on the desired port.  If this works you will get a socket that hangs and after disconnecting you will see an FDC file in the QMgr's global errors directory.  Until that low-level test works, it is guaranteed that MQ will ***not*** work.

However, if you are able to telnet from the client box to the QMgr host successfully and still get 2059, it is time to look at MQ's configuration.  There are security-related errors that give a very opaque error code to the client because that is just Good Security Practice.  In the case that it is an MQ security problem, there will be very detailed error messages on the QMgr side in its error logs and, assuming you have auths events enabled, emitted as event messages.

But, as mentioned earlier, it is a waste of time to look for MQ errors until and unless it is possible to connect from the client host to the MQ host using telnet on the MQ port.  So do the Telnet thing first, then check for MQ errors.

Comment: I am not able to telnet into phoenix server. I can telnet from any other local server into phoenix without any problem. no error messages in MQ log

Comment: Note I didn't say "telnet to phoenix server" I said telnet to it *on the MQ port*.  If it is a stock install of MQ, the listener is running, and the MQ service account has access to its own filesystem (not guaranteed on Windows systems!) a successful telnet connection *will* result in an FDC.  Either the telnet to the MQ server wasn't on MQ's port, or else the FDC files have been suppressed for that error message. Of the two, the more likely was that the telnet wasn't on the telnet port.  Try using `telnet phoenix.cat.com 1414` from `cloud-server.cat.com`.

Comment: my thinking was that if I can "telnet Phoenix.cat.com 1414" from any other local server; and cannot do it from cloud-server.cat.com; the it must be the problem with the cloud and not MQ server. Am I right?

Comment: Not necessarily. There may be firewall rules inbound, host-based firewall rules, IPSec or several other possible issues on  on phoenix.cat.com or at the network level. The thought that the intranet has connectivity and the cloud does not suggests a problem on the intranet but doesn't rule out problems on the cloud server.